# Minimize function with arrays as arguments

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a function, that i want to minimize. It is vectorized version of Ordinary Least Squares.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def lr_cost_function(theta, x, y, derivative = False, hypotesis=linear_hypotesis, polynom = 1):
    hyp = hypotesis(theta, x, polynom)
    print("Hyp: ", hyp.shape)
    dif = hyp - y
    print("Dif:", dif.shape)
    reuslt = dot(dif.T,dif)
    print("RES", reuslt.shape)
    return 1/len(y)*(dot(dif.T,dif)[0,0])

def linear_hypotesis(theta, x, polynom = 1):
    print(x.shape, theta.shape, type(theta))
    return np.dot(x, theta)
```

So I am calling minimize like this:

```
optimize.minimize(fun=lr_cost_function, x0=theta_copy, args=(x, y))
```

and my code can not be completed because in optimize.py argument x0 flatten and my vectorising is completely broken (line 822 in 0.13.2 scipy version). I even can't complete the code and see result, cause i have not enough memory and everything goes wrong on line with calculating dif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit confusing with dimensions of arrays, so got this error. My theta (it is 2-D array) should be flatten and all vectors (2-D arrays too) in code should be flatten, so code can work with minimum changes.